# Can not open my page after restarting Adobe Experience Manager 503 error

Tags: aem, osgi-bundle, aem-6

I wanted to connect my project with AEM 6.5

1. Cloned https://github.com/adobe/aem-project-archetype, and did mvn clean install
2. Built my project named aemeducation:

   mvn -B archetype:generate -D archetypeGroupId=com.adobe.aem  -D archetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype -D archetypeVersion=30 -D appTitle="AEM Education"  -D appId="aemeducation" -D groupId="com.company.aemeducation"
3. Did mvn clean install -PautoInstallBundle -PautoInstallPackage in newly created project
4. Even though I can see my site page by the content/aemeducation path, I get following errors in  the http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles:

[image]

And after restarting aem with bin/stop.bat,bin/start.bat files, I'm getting 503 error:
[image]

Maven, Java versions:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.4
Java version: 1.8.0_311, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\jre
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

error.log file:

```
6.11.2021 14:47:02.841 *ERROR* [FelixDispatchQueue] aemeducation.core FrameworkEvent ERROR (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve aemeducation.core [582](R 582.2): missing requirement [aemeducation.core [582](R 582.2)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.day.cq.wcm.api)(version>=1.29.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[aemeducation.core [582](R 582.2)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.day.cq.wcm.api)(version>=1.29.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve aemeducation.core [582](R 582.2): missing requirement [aemeducation.core [582](R 582.2)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.day.cq.wcm.api)(version>=1.29.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[aemeducation.core [582](R 582.2)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.day.cq.wcm.api)(version>=1.29.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Something in your project needs the marked version of these classes. Have you add the uberjar for your instance? Maybe your instance needs a service package, which contains the requested classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AEM 6.5 supports archetype 30 but not the vanilla one.

This is the basic system requirements for archetype 30:

**System Requirements**

[image]

**Documentation: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-core-components/using/developing/archetype/overview.html?lang=en**